# cocoa app crashes once in a while not reproduceable

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I sometimes get a strange error. I do the same thing several times and then sometimes the program just crashes. Most of the time it happens when I try to open a file Dialog or try to determine a random number. I have no idea what it could be. It would be great if someone could point me into the right direction.

Here is the Log I get and an image:

> 2013-03-23 17:40:11.040 ImageSorter[38065:303] -[**NSMallocBlock**
>   openFirstFile:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10015b170
>   2013-03-23 17:40:11.041 ImageSorter[38065:303] -[**NSMallocBlock**
>   openFirstFile:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10015b170
>   2013-03-23 17:40:11.046 ImageSorter[38065:303] (  0   CoreFoundation
>   0x00007fff8ce4fb06 **exceptionPreprocess + 198    1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x00007fff93b913f0 objc_exception_throw + 43  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x00007fff8cee640a -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] +
>   186   3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8ce3e02e
>   ___forwarding_** + 414    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8ce3de18 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 232  5   AppKit
>   0x00007fff8b141989 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 342     6
>   AppKit                              0x00007fff8b1417e7 -[NSControl
>   sendAction:to:] + 85  7   AppKit
>   0x00007fff8b14171b -[NSCell _sendActionFrom:] + 138   8   AppKit
>   0x00007fff8b13fc03 -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] +
>   1855  9   AppKit                              0x00007fff8b13f451
>   -[NSButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 504  10  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b13ebcc -[NSControl
>   mouseDown:] + 820     11  AppKit
>   0x00007fff8b13653e -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 6853  12  AppKit
>   0x00007fff8b132674 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 5761     13  AppKit
>   0x00007fff8b04824a -[NSApplication run] + 636     14  AppKit
>   0x00007fff8afecc06 NSApplicationMain + 869    15  ImageSorter
>   0x0000000100001142 main + 34  16  libdyld.dylib
>   0x00007fff93b107e1 start + 0 ) (lldb)

[image: Error on Screen]

### ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

The following happened after the first answers by gaige and Joshua Nozzi:

### ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I enabled Zombie Objects and when I ran it the first time it told me:

> Class _NSZombie_NSIBUserDefinedRuntimeAttributesConnector is
>   implemented in both ?? and ??. One of the two will be used. Which one
>   is undefined.

and

> CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction;
>   set CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS=1 in environment to log backtraces.

so I set CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS=1. Could the second warning be because of me running the open dialog in a background thread?

I ran it a few times now and I got several more errors but I can't really see what the problem is and why there isn't always the same error when I perform the same task. I don't expect anyone to actually go through all the error messages (they are more to illustrate my problem) but it would be great if someone could show how I can read and understand them (is there a good tutorial on that?):

Error 1:

> CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction;
>   created by: 0   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff89727959
>   _ZN2CA11Transaction4pushEv + 219 1   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff89727531 _ZN2CA11Transaction15ensure_implicitEv + 273 2
>   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff897273ce
>   _ZN2CA11Transaction9set_valueEj12_CAValueTypePKv + 40 3   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff89727362 +[CATransaction setDisableActions:] + 38 4   AppKit
>   0x00007fff81099ede -[NSScrollerImp _updateLayerGeometry] + 67 5
>   AppKit                              0x00007fff810994bd
>   -[NSScroller(NSInternal2) _replaceScrollerImp] + 368 6   AppKit                              0x00007fff81131778 -[NSScroller initWithCoder:] + 305 7   Foundation
>   0x00007fff85886fe9 _decodeObjectBinary + 2741 8   Foundation
>   0x00007fff85887dc6 -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _decodeArrayOfObjectsForKey:] +
>   1189 9   Foundation                          0x00007fff85888338
>   -[NSArray(NSArray) initWithCoder:] + 538 10  Foundation                          0x00007fff85886fe9 _decodeObjectBinary + 2741 11  Foundation
>   0x00007fff85886394 _decodeObject + 226 12  AppKit
>   0x00007fff80fb3631 -[NSView initWithCoder:] + 976 13  AppKit
>   0x00007fff8112ed17 -[NSScrollView initWithCoder:] + 335 14  Foundation
>   0x00007fff85886fe9 _decodeObjectBinary + 2741 15  Foundation
>   0x00007fff85886394 _decodeObject + 226

Error 2:

> *** -[**NSArrayM removeObjectAtIndex:]: index 19 beyond bounds [0 .. 18] 2013-03-24 11:48:25.953 Program[8316:303] (  0   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x00007fff82e07b06 __exceptionPreprocess + 198    1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x00007fff89b493f0 objc_exception_throw + 43  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x00007fff82da4a04 -[__NSArrayM removeObjectAtIndex:] + 276   3
>
>   AppKit                              0x00007fff8114915f -[NSBinder
>   _updateObservingRegistration:] + 258  4   AppKit                              0x00007fff8115619c -[NSBinder breakConnection] + 97     5   AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff8114155d -[NSObject(NSKeyValueBindingCreation)
>   bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options:] + 277     6   FinderKit
>
>   0x00007fff89e4d570 -[FI_TListViewController privateBindSettings] + 528
>     7   FinderKit                           0x00007fff89e38598
>   -[FI_TBrowserViewController(Configuration) bindViewSettings] + 83     8   FinderKit                           0x00007fff89ec17b7
>   -[FIFinderViewGutsController commonFinishInitialization] + 33     9   FinderKit                           0x00007fff89ebb439
>   -[FIFinderViewGutsController createBrowserViewWithViewStyle:] + 516   10  FinderKit                           0x00007fff89ebd48a
>   -[FIFinderViewGutsController buildBrowserView:] + 211     11  FinderKit                           0x00007fff89ebd931 -[FIFinderViewGutsController
>   _internalSetTargetPath:withViewStyle:] + 615  12  FinderKit                           0x00007fff89ebceb2 -[FIFinderViewGutsController
>   setTargetNode:withViewStyle:] + 523   13  FinderKit
>
>   0x00007fff89ebe584 -[FIFinderViewGutsController
>   deferredRetargetAndReloadForNode:] + 381  14  FinderKit
>
>   0x00007fff89ebe957 -[FIFinderViewGutsController
>   urlResolutionCompleted:] + 158    15  CoreFoundation
>
>   0x00007fff82db9eda _CFXNotificationPost + 2554    16  Foundation
>
>   0x00007fff85880e26 -[NSNotificationCenter
>   postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 64   17  Foundation
>
>   0x00007fff858cad3a __NSThreadPerformPerform + 225     18  CoreFoundation 
>   0x00007fff82d86b31
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17   19  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff82d86455
>   __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 245   20  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff82da97f5 __CFRunLoopRun + 789     21  CoreFoundation
>   0x00007fff82da90e2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290     22  HIToolbox
>   0x00007fff81f41eb4 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 209    23  HIToolbox
>   0x00007fff81f41c52 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 356   24  HIToolbox
>   0x00007fff81f41ae3 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 62     25 
>   AppKit                              0x00007fff81009563 _DPSNextEvent +
>   685   26  AppKit                              0x00007fff81008e22
>   -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 128    27  AppKit                              0x00007fff810001d3
>   -[NSApplication run] + 517    28  AppKit                              0x00007fff80fa4c06 NSApplicationMain + 869  29  JsonAnalyzer
>   0x000000010000ce82 main + 34  30  JsonAnalyzer
>   0x0000000100001604 start + 52     31  ???
>   0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3 )

Error 3:

> 2013-03-24 11:50:13.096 Program[8369:6b0b] *** Assertion failure in
>   -[FI_TSidebarView _expandItemEntry:expandChildren:startLevel:], /SourceCache/AppKit/AppKit-1187.37/TableView.subproj/NSOutlineView.m:1309
>   2013-03-24 11:50:13.097 Program[8369:6b0b] An uncaught exception was
>   raised 2013-03-24 11:50:13.098 Program[8369:6b0b] (null) should not be
>   expanded already! 2013-03-24 11:50:13.106 Program[8369:6b0b] (    0
>
>   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff82e07b06
>   __exceptionPreprocess + 198   1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff89b493f0 objc_exception_throw + 43    2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x00007fff82e07948 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 104   3
>
>   Foundation                          0x00007fff85844c82
>   -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 189     4
>
>   AppKit                              0x00007fff81158900 -[NSOutlineView
>   _expandItemEntry:expandChildren:startLevel:] + 1153   5   AppKit                              0x00007fff8113eb92 -[NSOutlineView _uncachedNumberOfRows] + 379     6
>
>   AppKit                              0x00007fff8113e9c8 -[NSTableView
>   _totalHeightOfTableView] + 187    7   AppKit                              0x00007fff8113e798 -[NSTableView _minimumFrameSize] + 74    8   AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff8109f0e1 -[NSClipView _minimumFrameSize] + 36   9   AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff8109e44e -[NSScrollView tile] + 1883    10  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff8109dc56 -[NSScrollView _tileWithoutRecursing] + 49     11 
>   AppKit                              0x00007fff810a0b89 -[NSScrollView
>   reflectScrolledClipView:] + 879   12  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff810324eb -[NSClipView _selfBoundsChanged] + 689     13  AppKit 
>   0x00007fff810a4a76 -[NSClipView setBoundsSize:] + 59  14  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff810a4915 -[NSView setBounds:] + 153     15  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff810a47f1 -[NSScrollView viewDidChangeBackingProperties] +
>   173   16  AppKit                              0x00007fff815cef69
>   -[NSView(NSInternal) _recursiveSendViewDidChangeBackingPropertiesFrom:toScaleFactor:colorSpace:invokingForSurfacePropertiesChange:alreadyUpdatedSurfaceProperties:]
>   + 1206    17  AppKit                              0x00007fff815cf020 -[NSView(NSInternal) _recursiveSendViewDidChangeBackingPropertiesFrom:toScaleFactor:colorSpace:invokingForSurfacePropertiesChange:alreadyUpdatedSurfaceProperties:]
>   + 1389    18  AppKit                              0x00007fff815cf020 -[NSView(NSInternal) _recursiveSendViewDidChangeBackingPropertiesFrom:toScaleFactor:colorSpace:invokingForSurfacePropertiesChange:alreadyUpdatedSurfaceProperties:]
>   + 1389    19  AppKit                              0x00007fff815cf020 -[NSView(NSInternal) _recursiveSendViewDidChangeBackingPropertiesFrom:toScaleFactor:colorSpace:invokingForSurfacePropertiesChange:alreadyUpdatedSurfaceProperties:]
>   + 1389    20  AppKit                              0x00007fff815cf020 -[NSView(NSInternal) _recursiveSendViewDidChangeBackingPropertiesFrom:toScaleFactor:colorSpace:invokingForSurfacePropertiesChange:alreadyUpdatedSurfaceProperties:]
>   + 1389    21  AppKit                              0x00007fff815cf020 -[NSView(NSInternal) _recursiveSendViewDidChangeBackingPropertiesFrom:toScaleFactor:colorSpace:invokingForSurfacePropertiesChange:alreadyUpdatedSurfaceProperties:]
>   + 1389    22  AppKit                              0x00007fff815cf020 -[NSView(NSInternal) _recursiveSendViewDidChangeBackingPropertiesFrom:toScaleFactor:colorSpace:invokingForSurfacePropertiesChange:alreadyUpdatedSurfaceProperties:]
>   + 1389    23  AppKit                              0x00007fff80fdd001 -[NSView addSubview:] + 1777     24  AppKit                              0x00007fff80f1962a -[NSBox setContentView:] + 81    25  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff80f18be0 -[NSSavePanel(NSSavePanelLayout)
>   _layoutViewsVerticallyAndResizeWindowToLastExpandedSize:accessoryViewHeight:]
>   + 4370    26  AppKit                              0x00007fff80f14a8b -[NSSavePanel _initPanelCommon] + 484    27  AppKit                              0x00007fff80f0f490 -[NSSavePanel
>   initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 334   28  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff80f0d1f7 +[NSSavePanel _crunchyRawUnbonedPanel] + 187   29 
>   JsonAnalyzer                        0x00000001000226d1 -[OpenFile
>   openFile] + 49    30  JsonAnalyzer
>
>   0x0000000100002266 -[AppController openMethod] + 182  31  Foundation
>
>   0x00007fff858cdcd2 __NSThread__main__ + 1345  32  libsystem_c.dylib
>
>   0x00007fff845f67a2 _pthread_start + 327   33  libsystem_c.dylib
>
>   0x00007fff845e31e1 thread_start + 13 ) 2013-03-24 11:50:13.109
>   Program[8369:6b0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '(null) should not be
>   expanded already!'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff82e07b06 **exceptionPreprocess + 198  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x00007fff89b493f0 objc_exception_throw + 43  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x00007fff82e07948 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 104   3
>
>   Foundation                          0x00007fff85844c82
>   -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 189     4
>
>   AppKit                              0x00007fff81158900 -[NSOutlineView
>   _expandItemEntry:expandChildren:startLevel:] + 1153   5   AppKit                              0x00007fff8113eb92 -[NSOutlineView _uncachedNumberOfRows] + 379     6
>
>   AppKit                              0x00007fff8113e9c8 -[NSTableView
>   _totalHeightOfTableView] + 187    7   AppKit                              0x00007fff8113e798 -[NSTableView _minimumFrameSize] + 74    8   AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff8109f0e1 -[NSClipView _minimumFrameSize] + 36   9   AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff8109e44e -[NSScrollView tile] + 1883    10  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff8109dc56 -[NSScrollView _tileWithoutRecursing] + 49     11 
>   AppKit                              0x00007fff810a0b89 -[NSScrollView
>   reflectScrolledClipView:] + 879   12  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff810324eb -[NSClipView _selfBoundsChanged] + 689     13  AppKit 
>   0x00007fff810a4a76 -[NSClipView setBoundsSize:] + 59  14  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff810a4915 -[NSView setBounds:] + 153     15  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff810a47f1 -[NSScrollView viewDidChangeBackingProperties] +
>   173   16  AppKit                              0x00007fff815cef69
>   -[NSView(NSInternal) _recursiveSendViewDidChangeBackingPropertiesFrom:toScaleFactor:colorSpace:invokingForSurfacePropertiesChange:alreadyUpdatedSurfaceProperties:]
>   + 1206    17  AppKit                              0x00007fff815cf020 -[NSView(NSInternal) _recursiveSendViewDidChangeBackingPropertiesFrom:toScaleFactor:colorSpace:invokingForSurfacePropertiesChange:alreadyUpdatedSurfaceProperties:]
>   + 1389    18  AppKit                              0x00007fff815cf020 -[NSView(NSInternal) _recursiveSendViewDidChangeBackingPropertiesFrom:toScaleFactor:colorSpace:invokingForSurfacePropertiesChange:alreadyUpdatedSurfaceProperties:]
>   + 1389    19  AppKit                              0x00007fff815cf020 -[NSView(NSInternal) _recursiveSendViewDidChangeBackingPropertiesFrom:toScaleFactor:colorSpace:invokingForSurfacePropertiesChange:alreadyUpdatedSurfaceProperties:]
>   + 1389    20  AppKit                              0x00007fff815cf020 -[NSView(NSInternal) _recursiveSendViewDidChangeBackingPropertiesFrom:toScaleFactor:colorSpace:invokingForSurfacePropertiesChange:alreadyUpdatedSurfaceProperties:]
>   + 1389    21  AppKit                              0x00007fff815cf020 -[NSView(NSInternal) _recursiveSendViewDidChangeBackingPropertiesFrom:toScaleFactor:colorSpace:invokingForSurfacePropertiesChange:alreadyUpdatedSurfaceProperties:]
>   + 1389    22  AppKit                              0x00007fff815cf020 -[NSView(NSInternal) _recursiveSendViewDidChangeBackingPropertiesFrom:toScaleFactor:colorSpace:invokingForSurfacePropertiesChange:alreadyUpdatedSurfaceProperties:]
>   + 1389    23  AppKit                              0x00007fff80fdd001 -[NSView addSubview:] + 1777     24  AppKit                              0x00007fff80f1962a -[NSBox setContentView:] + 81    25  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff80f18be0 -[NSSavePanel(NSSavePanelLayout)
>   _layoutViewsVerticallyAndResizeWindowToLastExpandedSize:accessoryViewHeight:]
>   + 4370    26  AppKit                              0x00007fff80f14a8b -[NSSavePanel _initPanelCommon] + 484    27  AppKit                              0x00007fff80f0f490 -[NSSavePanel
>   initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 334   28  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff80f0d1f7 +[NSSavePanel _crunchyRawUnbonedPanel] + 187   29 
>   JsonAnalyzer                        0x00000001000226d1 -[OpenFile
>   openFile] + 49    30  JsonAnalyzer
>
>   0x0000000100002266 -[AppController openMethod] + 182  31  Foundation
>
>   0x00007fff858cdcd2 __NSThread__main** + 1345  32  libsystem_c.dylib
>   0x00007fff845f67a2 _pthread_start + 327   33  libsystem_c.dylib
>   0x00007fff845e31e1 thread_start + 13 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminate
>   called throwing an exception (lldb)

Error 4:

> 2013-03-24 12:07:53.299 Program[9024:6d0b] An uncaught exception was
>   raised 2013-03-24 12:07:53.301 Program[9024:6d0b] endUpdates called
>   without a beginUpdates 2013-03-24 12:07:53.309 Program[9024:6d0b] (   0
>   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff82e07b06
>   **exceptionPreprocess + 198   1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff89b493f0 objc_exception_throw + 43    2   AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff8118421b -[NSTableRowData endUpdates] + 205     3
>
>   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff82db9eda
>   _CFXNotificationPost + 2554   4   Foundation                          0x00007fff85880e26 -[NSNotificationCenter
>   postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 64   5   AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff80ff216e -[NSView _postFrameChangeNotification] + 259   6
>
>   AppKit                              0x00007fff80fdc843 -[NSView
>   setFrameSize:] + 1352     7   AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff81031cb1 -[NSClipView setFrameSize:] + 394  8   AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff80fdbf8e -[NSView setFrame:] + 299  9   AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff8109fa2f -[NSScrollView _setContentViewFrame:] + 596    10 
>   AppKit                              0x00007fff8109e43a -[NSScrollView
>   tile] + 1863  11  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff8109dc56 -[NSScrollView _tileWithoutRecursing] + 49     12 
>   AppKit                              0x00007fff8109dbda -[NSScrollView
>   _update] + 30     13  AppKit                              0x00007fff80fdc748 -[NSView setFrameSize:] + 1101   14  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff810a2e7c -[NSScrollView setFrameSize:] + 1131   15  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff80fdbf8e -[NSView setFrame:] + 299  16  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff810311f2 -[NSView resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 1502   17 
>   AppKit                              0x00007fff81030337 -[NSView
>   resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:] + 318     18  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff80fdc748 -[NSView setFrameSize:] + 1101     19  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff80fdbf8e -[NSView setFrame:] + 299  20  FinderKit
>
>   0x00007fff89ec91aa -[FI_TSidebarSplitterController
>   splitView:resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:] + 1232  21  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff811fdc70 -[NSSplitView resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:] + 717    22
>   AppKit                              0x00007fff80fdc748 -[NSView
>   setFrameSize:] + 1101     23  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff80fdbf8e -[NSView setFrame:] + 299  24  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff810311f2 -[NSView resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 1502   25 
>   AppKit                              0x00007fff81030337 -[NSView
>   resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:] + 318     26  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff80fdc748 -[NSView setFrameSize:] + 1101     27  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff80fdbf8e -[NSView setFrame:] + 299  28  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff810311f2 -[NSView resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 1502   29 
>   AppKit                              0x00007fff81030337 -[NSView
>   resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:] + 318     30  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff80fdc748 -[NSView setFrameSize:] + 1101     31  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff80fdbf8e -[NSView setFrame:] + 299  32  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff810311f2 -[NSView resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 1502   33 
>   AppKit                              0x00007fff81030337 -[NSView
>   resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:] + 318     34  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff80fdc748 -[NSView setFrameSize:] + 1101     35  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff80fdbf8e -[NSView setFrame:] + 299  36  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff80f13bea -[NSNavFinderViewFileBrowser setFrameSize:] + 152
>     37  AppKit                              0x00007fff80fdbf8e -[NSView
>   setFrame:] + 299  38  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff81118692 -[NSBox _tile:] + 243  39  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff80f1964b -[NSBox setContentView:] + 114     40  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff80f18be0 -[NSSavePanel(NSSavePanelLayout)
>   _layoutViewsVerticallyAndResizeWindowToLastExpandedSize:accessoryViewHeight:]
>   + 4370    41  AppKit                              0x00007fff80f14a8b -[NSSavePanel _initPanelCommon] + 484    42  AppKit                              0x00007fff80f0f490 -[NSSavePanel
>   initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 334   43  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff80f0d1f7 +[NSSavePanel _crunchyRawUnbonedPanel] + 187   44 
>   JsonAnalyzer                        0x00000001000226d1 -[OpenFile
>   openFile] + 49    45  JsonAnalyzer
>
>   0x0000000100002266 -[AppController openMethod] + 182  46  Foundation
>
>   0x00007fff858cdcd2 __NSThread__main** + 1345  47  libsystem_c.dylib
>   0x00007fff845f67a2 _pthread_start + 327   48  libsystem_c.dylib
>   0x00007fff845e31e1 thread_start + 13 ) 2013-03-24 12:07:53.315
>   Program[9024:6d0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSTableViewException', reason: 'endUpdates called without a
>   beginUpdates'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff82e07b06 **exceptionPreprocess + 198  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x00007fff89b493f0 objc_exception_throw + 43  2   AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff8118421b -[NSTableRowData endUpdates] + 205     3
>
>   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff82db9eda
>   _CFXNotificationPost + 2554   4   Foundation                          0x00007fff85880e26 -[NSNotificationCenter
>   postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 64   5   AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff80ff216e -[NSView _postFrameChangeNotification] + 259   6
>
>   AppKit                              0x00007fff80fdc843 -[NSView
>   setFrameSize:] + 1352     7   AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff81031cb1 -[NSClipView setFrameSize:] + 394  8   AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff80fdbf8e -[NSView setFrame:] + 299  9   AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff8109fa2f -[NSScrollView _setContentViewFrame:] + 596    10 
>   AppKit                              0x00007fff8109e43a -[NSScrollView
>   tile] + 1863  11  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff8109dc56 -[NSScrollView _tileWithoutRecursing] + 49     12 
>   AppKit                              0x00007fff8109dbda -[NSScrollView
>   _update] + 30     13  AppKit                              0x00007fff80fdc748 -[NSView setFrameSize:] + 1101   14  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff810a2e7c -[NSScrollView setFrameSize:] + 1131   15  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff80fdbf8e -[NSView setFrame:] + 299  16  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff810311f2 -[NSView resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 1502   17 
>   AppKit                              0x00007fff81030337 -[NSView
>   resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:] + 318     18  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff80fdc748 -[NSView setFrameSize:] + 1101     19  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff80fdbf8e -[NSView setFrame:] + 299  20  FinderKit
>
>   0x00007fff89ec91aa -[FI_TSidebarSplitterController
>   splitView:resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:] + 1232  21  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff811fdc70 -[NSSplitView resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:] + 717    22
>   AppKit                              0x00007fff80fdc748 -[NSView
>   setFrameSize:] + 1101     23  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff80fdbf8e -[NSView setFrame:] + 299  24  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff810311f2 -[NSView resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 1502   25 
>   AppKit                              0x00007fff81030337 -[NSView
>   resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:] + 318     26  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff80fdc748 -[NSView setFrameSize:] + 1101     27  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff80fdbf8e -[NSView setFrame:] + 299  28  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff810311f2 -[NSView resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 1502   29 
>   AppKit                              0x00007fff81030337 -[NSView
>   resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:] + 318     30  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff80fdc748 -[NSView setFrameSize:] + 1101     31  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff80fdbf8e -[NSView setFrame:] + 299  32  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff810311f2 -[NSView resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 1502   33 
>   AppKit                              0x00007fff81030337 -[NSView
>   resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:] + 318     34  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff80fdc748 -[NSView setFrameSize:] + 1101     35  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff80fdbf8e -[NSView setFrame:] + 299  36  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff80f13bea -[NSNavFinderViewFileBrowser setFrameSize:] + 152
>     37  AppKit                              0x00007fff80fdbf8e -[NSView
>   setFrame:] + 299  38  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff81118692 -[NSBox _tile:] + 243  39  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff80f1964b -[NSBox setContentView:] + 114     40  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff80f18be0 -[NSSavePanel(NSSavePanelLayout)
>   _layoutViewsVerticallyAndResizeWindowToLastExpandedSize:accessoryViewHeight:]
>   + 4370    41  AppKit                              0x00007fff80f14a8b -[NSSavePanel _initPanelCommon] + 484    42  AppKit                              0x00007fff80f0f490 -[NSSavePanel
>   initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 334   43  AppKit
>
>   0x00007fff80f0d1f7 +[NSSavePanel _crunchyRawUnbonedPanel] + 187   44 
>   JsonAnalyzer                        0x00000001000226d1 -[OpenFile
>   openFile] + 49    45  JsonAnalyzer
>
>   0x0000000100002266 -[AppController openMethod] + 182  46  Foundation
>
>   0x00007fff858cdcd2 __NSThread__main** + 1345  47  libsystem_c.dylib
>   0x00007fff845f67a2 _pthread_start + 327   48  libsystem_c.dylib
>   0x00007fff845e31e1 thread_start + 13 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminate
>   called throwing an exception (lldb)

Error 5:

> 2013-03-24 12:07:01.791 Program[8985:303] *** -[__NSDictionaryI
>   countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: message sent to
>   deallocated instance 0x106b80490 (lldb)

Error 6:

> 2013-03-24 12:13:05.343 Program[9236:6d0b] start objc[9236]: Class
>   _NSZombie_NSIBUserDefinedRuntimeAttributesConnector is implemented in both ?? and ??. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
>   2013-03-24 12:13:05.580 Program[9236:6d0b] *** -[__NSDictionaryM
>   count]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x106b70080 (lldb)

Comment: "Most of the time it happens when I try to open a file Dialog or try to determine a random number." - do you get the same error in those two cases?

Comment: For me it looks the same but probably not... I'm quite new to objective c and programming in general and for me it's really hard to read the error messages. Is there some kind of explanation on how to read them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is likely to be in the first line: `-[NSMallocBlock openFirstFile:]`.   In this case, it's clear that the `-openFirstFile:` message is being sent from the responder to a block that is expected to be something else, but has been reused.

Based on the `-[NSControl sendAction:to:]` later in the stack trace, this is happening in response to some action (likely clicking the Open button in the standard file window).

In this case, it appears that something is being pointed to by a delegate an IBOutlet and is being released.

I would look at using Zombies (within Instruments, or just enabling them when running normally by using `Enable Zombie Objects` in the Diagnostics section of the Run area of your Scheme.

Comment: So basically what I said six minutes earlier? ;-)

Comment: Actually, your answer didn't show up until after I submitted mine, so yes, you may have hit submit 6 minutes earlier, but it's not as if I read your reply and then wrote mine, which is what you're implying here.   I would have deleted my answer once I noticed yours, but I believe inclusion of non-Instruments Zombies and my pointing out how to recognize it was more thorough, so I left it for OP to decide.

Comment: I enabled Zombie Objects and the first thing was that I got the error message (don't know if its related): "CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction; set CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS=1 in environment to log backtraces.". so I did that and now after some runs I have several different error messages and I don't understand one... is there a good guide on how to interpret these error messages? I would like to learn it myself and not post it here every time. I edited my post with what happened after I enabled Zombie Objects.

Comment: @Marty there's a lot of stuff going on there, and it's likely not just one cause.  CoreAnimation warnings of that kind are usually related to either a missing beginTransaction/endTransaction pair if you are doing manual automation or with layers or views going away while they are still animating.   However, there seem to be some other retain/release related problems going on as well, indicating that you're manually releasing (or not retaining) data that you're using elsewhere.  If you can, you might want to consider ARC, otherwise, Instruments-based Zombies might be more helpful.

Comment: I already have ARC turned on. But maybe I'm messing it up with something. Its probably a good idea to read a lot more about memory management. Thanks

Comment: Take a close look at your bindings in your .xib files.   Considering that `NSBinding` shows up in at least one of the traces, you might have a reference to an owner or view that is getting automatically released by ARC.

Answer (score 2):

This is almost certainly a memory management error on your part. Whatever pointer you're expecting to point to the object to which you send the -openFirstFile: message isn't any more, because that object was released and another now lives at its address - an address you're not supposed to touch because it no longer belongs to your app.

Use Instruments (Zombies instrument) to track down the error.

Answer (score 0):

For those looking at Error 4's "endUpdates called without a beginUpdates" on a tableview, it may be due to the update of the view (e.g. a [tableview reloadData] call ) occurring outside of the main thread.

See this similar question for more info: [NSArrayController rearrangeObjects error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12094894/nsarraycontroller-rearrangeobjects-error)

Answer (score -1):

the bad access error generally occurs when you are trying to reach something outside of range i.e. the 8 the spot of an array of 7. Are you sure this is not the case? This would be my first checking point, making sure you don't exceed the limits  :)

Comment: Err, sorry, no. You get an "index out of bounds" exception when you try to access an object at an index that's, well, out of bounds of the container.

Comment: @JoshuaNozzi, only if it's a Cocoa collection. C arrays don't have bounds checking and C++ containers have methods that ignore them as well (though this is probably not C++ related).

Comment: You're correct, zneak, but the stack trace provided by the OP doesn't suggest this is the case at all. An event is fired and bubbles through the responder chain until it reaches what's *supposed* to be an object that the app owns and that responds to -openFirstFile: ... this is a memory management issue involving Cocoa objects. :-)